Not able to create Spark session using getOrCreate function
While I have written a simple PySpark code, it continues to fail at building Spark Session. Here is the code:
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark import SparkConf  

from lib.logger import Log4j  
from lib.utils import get_spark_app_config  

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    conf = get_spark_app_config()  
    spark = SparkSession.builder \  
        .config(conf=conf) \  
        .getOrCreate()  

logger = Log4j(spark)  

logger.info("Starting HelloSpark")  
conf_out = spark.sparkContext.getConf()  
logger.info(conf_out.toDebugString())  

logger.info("Finished HelloSpark")

My Spark version (3.14.1) and PySpark packages version are same. The Python version (3.12) and packages in conda are of the same version as well. Still not able to figure out anything after searching thoroughly. Can someone suggest what could be wrong here?

I am able to create SparkSession using below code from  Data Analysis with Python and PySpark book by Jonathan Rioux
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Analyzing data").getOrCreate()
book = spark.read.text(r'\pyspark\sample-data.txt')
book.show()
Here is output of my file
|               value|
+--------------------+
|The Project Guten...|
|                    |
|This eBook is for...|
|almost no restric...|
|re-use it under t...|
|with this eBook o...|

Could you show us the error ?
Your indent is incorrect.
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark import SparkConf  

from lib.logger import Log4j  
from lib.utils import get_spark_app_config  

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    conf = get_spark_app_config()  
    spark = SparkSession.builder \  
        .config(conf=conf) \  
        .getOrCreate()  

    logger = Log4j(spark)  

    logger.info("Starting HelloSpark")  
    conf_out = spark.sparkContext.getConf()  
    logger.info(conf_out.toDebugString())  

    logger.info("Finished HelloSpark")

PS: It's not a good practice to use "*" (you may overrides built-in python modules, variables, functions or classes if they have the same name). import your sparkSession as follow : from pyspark.sql import SparkSession.
